# hive/sql:count each user_id gets how many uid

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

There is a table like:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
|    uid    | user_id |   month    |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| d23fsdfsa |     101 | 2017-01-02 |
| 43gdasc   |     102 | 2017-05-06 |
| b65hrfd   |     101 | 2017-08-11 |
| 1wseda    |     103 | 2017-09-13 |
| vdfhryd   |     101 | 2017-08-06 |
| b6thd3d   |     105 | 2017-05-03 |
| ve32h65   |     102 | 2017-01-02 |
| 43gdasc   |     102 | 2017-09-06 |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

How can one count each user_id where if the user_id appears in the same month, then only count one?

The final table should look like below: (because '101' has two uid in the same month so it only counts one for it)

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | count_num |
+---------+-----------+
|     101 |         2 |
|     102 |         3 |
|     103 |         1 |
|     105 |         1 |
+---------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the number of distinct months for each user.  If so:

```
select user_id, count(distinct trunc(month, 'MONTH')) as count_num
from t
group by user_id;
```